# Android ToolBar vanishes suddenly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've replaced the ActionBar in my Activity with a ToolBar. But when the activity loads it shows and vanishes within a second. The layout of my activity is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_driver_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ALLIE"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_driver_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_driver_name"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="NISSAN 389 - VQX"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_driver_vehicle"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4.75"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I've added a custom view which was working correctly with the actionbar before as follows :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_maps, null);
        toolbar.addView(v);
```

As the activity loads and the map zooms in to the current location, the toolbar vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting that the fragment is below `@+id/header` but the toolbar has id `toolbar`. Change one of those so both are the same

Your fragment is filling your activity so at first you can see your toolbar but as soon as the fragment is loaded it is over the toolbar.